# Jquery search table td last character of string

Tags: javascript, jquery

if i search 'abc' tan result is like 'testoneabc.com,testtwoabc.com,hwvdhgabc.com'

but my code search  like this  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uqoluJ-ZTLYnlxQmZqVjNuYjg/view?usp=drivesdk

but i want like this https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9uqoluJ-ZTLWXJ6dmFWZlNka2M/view?usp=drivesdk

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><th>Unique ID</th><th>Random ID</th></tr>
  <tr><td>testabc.com</td><td>442</td></tr>
  <tr><td>teerfrestabc.com</td><td>556</td></tr>
  <tr><td>teerfsderestabc.com</td><td>4666</td></tr>
  <tr><td>teerasdefrestabc.com</td><td>334</td></tr>
  <tr><td>teerfrestabcdsad.com</td><td>54364</td></tr>
</table>
<br />
<input type="text" id="search" placeholder="  live search"></input>
```

Script:

```
$("#search").on("keyup", function() {
  var value = $(this).val();

  $("table tr").each(function(index) {
    if (index !== 0) {
      $row = $(this);

      var id = $row.find("td:first").text();

      if (id.indexOf(value) !== 0) {
        $row.hide();
      }
      else {
        $row.show();
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This code shows result like this

[image]

Comment: i am trying to edit this code   http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D6nzC/

Comment: By rules of Stack Overflow, please make sure all relevant information is contained within your question. Links to additional resources are welcome, but the question needs to make sense without them, in case they go stale. Please add your code and data to the question itself, not Google Drive and JSFiddle.

Comment: is that okay now...?